# Find index of item within a specific div where multiple divs exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I have a HTML set up of many images, wrapped in divs, which are wrapped 4 items to a row. Example, 4 items per row, 2 rows:

```
<div class="staff-wrapper">
    <div class="staff-row">
        <div class="staff-item">
            <img>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-item">
            <img>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-item">
            <img>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-item">
            <img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="staff-row">
        <div class="staff-item">
            <img>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-item">
            <img>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-item">
            <img>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-item">
            <img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to identify, when clicking on the image, which index this item has within its row.

So if the 3rd item of a row is clicked, the value will be `3`. The possible answers should only ever be 1,2,3 or 4 because there can only ever be maximum 4 items per row.

I almost have this, however I'm finding the result is always based on the whole of the list of items, so I'm getting answers like `7` for the last item. Instead this should be 3`, because it's the third item in it's row.

Here is what I have:

```
var itemPosition = $(".staff-row img").index(this);
```

Any ideas?

### JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vo6hz1zc/

Comment: _“the result is always based on the whole of the list of items, so I'm getting answers like 7 for the last item. Instead this should be 3”_ – that’s a “problem” that a simple modulo 4 could have easily solved already …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be finding the index of the *parent* of the `this` which is `img` that's clicked.

Also add `1` as indexes start from `0`

```
$('.staff-item img').click(function(){
    var itemPosition = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    console.log(itemPosition);
});
```

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo6hz1zc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is getting the right row first, and then get the index you could loop trough the rows:

```
$('.staff-item img').click(function(){
    $this=$(this);
    var itemPosition = $(".staff-row").each(function(){
        itemPosition=$("img",$(this)).index($this);
        if(itemPosition>-1){
            console.log(itemPosition);
        }
    });
});
```

A better option is just select the child from this if thats possible is selecting the parent and search in the parent:

```
$('.staff-item img').click(function(){
    var itemPosition = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log(itemPosition)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.staff-item img').click(function(){
  var itemPosition = $(this).closest(".staff-row").find(".staff-item img").index(this);
  alert(itemPosition);
});
```

Updated your jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prakashlaxkar/vo6hz1zc/3/ as well. Thanks